# Why did my github merge go in the wrong direction?

Tags: git, github, merge, language-agnostic, github-desktop

I have [a repo on GitHub](https://github.com/JC3/MLExamples) that had a branch (`handtracking`) that I was doing some development on. In the mean time I had made a number of changes on `master`, and I wanted to merge them *from* `master` *to* `handtracking`, so that my dev branch would have the latest changes.

I used the Github Desktop client on Windows to do this, I did not use the command line. I performed the following steps (in Github Desktop unless otherwise noted):

1. Committed all changes, sync'd everything up to prepare.
2. Switch to `master` branch via the branch pulldown.
3. Created a pull request in the client and selected the destination branch; it  clearly stated "from `master` into `handtracking`".
4. Submitted it, then [opened it on the web site](https://github.com/JC3/MLExamples/pull/7), where it also very clearly states `master` -> `handtracking`.
5. There were conflicts; so I chose to resolve them on the web site editor. For some reason when I did this, it committed the resolution to `master`, although I don't see an actual commit for this anywhere. This part is where I became confused.
6. I then clicked the merge button on the pull request on the web site, which still said it was going from `master` into `handtracking`.

But then, at this point, it created two commits. [One from `handtracking` into `master`](https://github.com/JC3/MLExamples/commit/beee8e1aa99f69ab9c76a3cc6b3c8a8fb09df198), which is where all the wrong way stuff happened; and then [a second one from the updated `master` back into an apparently new `handtracking` branch](https://github.com/JC3/MLExamples/commit/f00b2568c83553fef4cd5960736a4b74341c70fe) ("apparently new" because the color changed on the Insights -> Network view).

The second commit is the one that referenced the pull request, and is the only one I expected to happen. The first seemed to have come out of nowhere, and merged all the `handtracking` changes into `master`, which is what I didn't want to happen.

The network graph now looks like this (the highlighted bit is what this whole process created):

[image]

But I had expected it to be like this:

[image]

My questions are:

1. What the heck happened? What was my mistake? I can't understand where that first `handtracking` -> `master` merge came from, especially because at every point there were descriptions stating clearly that the merge was going the other, correct direction.
2. How could I have avoided this while still using Github Desktop + the web site? Or is doing this only possible with the command line client?

I know (I think?) I've done this before with no issues, I can't figure out what was different this time.

Comment: I can't really answer the question, but I will note that I find that the GitHub network graph is (a) often wildly wrong and (b) useless. If you find it useful, well, so do many others: GitHub removed it a few weeks ago, then they put it back after a lot of outcry. See, e.g., https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Network-Graph-Missing/td-p/22982

Comment: @torek Wow; glad I missed those forum battles. I like the graphical branch views in general, I just wish github's was a little smarter about its right angles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use git and read up on how to merge without the web gui as it is very limited. The process is very straight forward. At this stage if you need you can revert your changes, otherwise just use git. What you ended up doing was a sync merge.